# Postfix / Dovecot / MySQL- doesn't work!

Tags: mysql, email, postfix, dovecot

I have just installed a Mail- Server on Postfix and Dovecot using MySQL to authenticate the user. But if I try to conntect to the Server via Outlook or Thunderbird, the following Error appears in the mail.err: postfix/smtpd[4937]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms Any Idea how to fix this? Thx :)

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu:) Please add the postfix and dovecot configuration files to your question eg: `/etc/postfix/master.conf`, `/etc/postfix/master.conf`and the output of the command `doveconf -n`.

Comment: Output of dovecot -n:
http://pastebin.com/QZHvHZCM

Theres no master.conf in /etc/postfix. But heres the master.cf:
http://pastebin.com/cbhBXQzX

main.cf:
http://pastebin.com/YY5cAFzZ

Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

I will need some more information on what exactly you are trying to do. Do you connect for sending email via smtp? or for receiving? Eg. pop3 or imap?

```
#For your main.cf: proxy:mysql:
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual/mysql-aliases.cf
# Eg changes to
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual/mysql-aliases.cf

# I use, no idea if it is any different
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

This is not guaranteed to be the solution but you could try to:

```
# master.cf: 

# You need to enable smtpd. Line 13 in your master.cf paste.
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd

I am not sure if it has any different effect, however worth a try if the above is not fixing your issue:
(Removed some configuration options, the milter line I supply below, is also possible to leave out.)    

#enabling submission on port 587, force ssl.

submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

# Unless you have created the mail dirs you might need to
# in your dovecot config.
lda_mailbox_autocreate = yes
lda_mailbox_autosubscribe = yes
#you could also use higher restrictions
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0660
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imaps {
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3s {
    ssl = yes
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for ure answer! Ive tried it, but it didn't work. Then i took a look in the mail.err again and saw this: postfix/proxymap[15342]: error: open /etc/postfix/virtual/mysql-aliases.cf: Permission denied
What does that mean? Maybe thats the reason why its not working! How can i fix it?

Comment: I will post some important stuff tomorrow. Ive fixed the Permission error but theres still this SASL- Error left :( Thank u for ure efforts :)

Comment: feel free to add me at skype `ablacksheep-` I had a quick look again today and i got some new questions, ideas and maybe the correct answer, but to short on time now. Will come back with it later. laters=)

Comment: @user287331 : Can you explain exactly what you wanna achieve? Are you trying to auth the clients (outlook\thunderbird eg.) with client certificates? or only make dovecot use ssl+tls connections for imap pop3? and or making postfix smtp users to send mail with dovecot as the auth? or all of it? Sorry for late follow up, but so busy nowdays : )